# Looping through table and it runs forever crashing browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
// * one button to do everything
// * ---Save button-----
$(document).on("click", "#devSaveBtn", function() {
  var answer = window.confirm("Save changes");
  if (answer) {
    // ! -------Gets the input from record row--------
    let testSelect = document
      .getElementById("tktBody")
      .querySelector(".selected")
      .querySelector("#tktNumStatus").innerHTML; // * the selected ticket status

    let selectTkt = document
      .getElementById("tktBody")
      .querySelector(".selected")
      .querySelector("#tktNum").innerHTML; // * the selected ticket

    // * Table variable
const table = document.getElementById("steptable");
// ! Since there is an extra th element in the table (the headers) the loop has to start from 1 and not zero
for (var i = 1, row; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  // * iterate through rows
  // * rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
  ObjType = table.rows[i].cells[2].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
  Name = table.rows[i].cells[3].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
  Business = table.rows[i].cells[4].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
  Project = table.rows[i].cells[5].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
  Deployer_Candidate =
    table.rows[i].cells[6].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
  Description = table.rows[i].cells[7].querySelector(".vcheck").value;

  // * Condition to prevent the other rows from being inserted with the sql insert statement
  if (Name === "") {
    continue;
  }

  console.log(row);
  console.log("ObjType = " + ObjType);
  console.log("Name = " + Name);
  console.log("Business = " + Business);
  console.log("Project = " + Project);
  console.log("Deployer_Candidate = " + Deployer_Candidate);
  console.log("Description = " + Description);

  // * Array to store the rows
  const arr = [];

  arr.push(row);

  console.log(arr);

  // * Loop that will run the sql statement for each row in the table
  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    // * condition to break the loop so it does not repeat with the clone rows you can't see

        if (testSelect != "NEW") {
          //prettier-ignore
          callDB("UPDATE Table SET OBJ_NAME = 'test', OBJ_TYPE = '" + ObjType + "', DEPLOYER_BUSINESS = '" + Business + "', DEPLOYER_CANDIDATE = '" + Deployer_Candidate + "', DEPLOYER_PROJECT = 'test', DESCRIPTION = 'test' WHERE TICKET_NUM = '" + selectTkt + "'");
          console.log("response one");
        }

        // * conditional for new tickets being created
        if (testSelect === "NEW") {
          //prettier-ignore
          DB(
            "INSERT INTO Table(SEQ_NUM, OBJ_TYPE, OBJ_NAME, DEVELOPER_NAME, CHANGE_NUM, DEPLOYER_BUSINESS, DEPLOY_DATETIME, DEPLOYER_PROJECT, DEPLOYER_CANDIDATE , STATUS, TICKET_NUM, CHANGE_ENGINEER, DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1 + "','" + ObjType + "','" + Name + "','test', '.','" + Business + "', '.', '" + Project + "', '" + Deployer_Candidate + "', 'existing', '" + testnewRecord.tktNum + "', '" + testnewRecord.chngEngr + "', '" + Description + "')"
          );
          console.log("response two");
        } else {}
        return i;
      }
    }
    // * Forces page reload
    location.reload();
  }
  // * else display service message
  else {
    console.log("Service Cancel");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- * Main Record Table *-->
<div id="steptablecontainer">
  <div id="steptable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
    <table id="steptable" class="compact cell-border no-footer dataTable row-border" role="grid">
      <thead id="recordTableHead">
        <tr role="row">
          <!-- * Names For Each Container *-->
          <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="" style="width: 25px; max-width: 25px;"></th>
          <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="" style="width: 50px; background-image: none; max-width: 25px;">Record</th>
          <th class="componentellipsis sorting_disabled" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Component" style="width: 200px; max-width: 50px;">Type</th>
          <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type" style="width: 125px;">Name</th>
          <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Test" style="width: 100px; max-width: 50px;">Business</th>
          <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Dev" style="width: 200px; max-width: 50px;">Project</th>
          <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type" style="width: 150px; max-width: 125px;">Deployer Candidate</th>
          <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type" style="width: 400px; max-width: 200px; overflow: hidden;">Description
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <!-- * Sample Record (Cloned then changed) *-->

      <tbody id="recordRow0" style="display: none; border: 10px;" class="recordRow">
        <tr role="row" class="" data-true-step="1">
          <td class="noncomponentswidth">
            <button class="readyonlyhidden" id="removeRecordBtn0" title="Remove Record" value="0">
                                                <span><i style="font-size:18px;" class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></span>
                                            </button>
          </td>


          <!-- * Record intializing *-->
          <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordCount">1</td>

          <!-- * Drop down for the obj_type *-->
          <div id="container">
            <td class="componentellipsis" id="recordTypeWrapper">
              <select id="OBJ_TYPE" class="vcheck">
                <option value="TP">TP</option>
                <option value="Workflow">Workflow</option>
                <option value="Package">Package</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </div>


          <!-- * Container for Obj Name *-->
          <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordObjName">
            <p>
              <!-- * Input for Obj Name *-->
              <input type="text" id="OBJ_NAME" name="Object Name" placeholder="" class="vcheck" required minlength="8">
            </p>
          </td>

          <!-- * Deployer Business *-->
          <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDevName">
            <input type="text" id="DEPLOYER_BUSINESS" name="Business Name" placeholder="" style="display: none;">
            <select id="DEPLOYER_BUSINESS" class="vcheck">
              <!-- * Picklist for TP *-->
              <option value="APPM">APPM</option>
              <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
              <option value="CorporateAP">CorporateAP</option>
              <option value="CorporateCredit">CorporateCredit</option>
              <option value="CorporateEHS">CorporateEHS</option>
              <option value="CorporateFinance">CorporateFinance</option>
              <option value="CorporateFinancialServices">
                CorporateFinancialServices
              </option>
              <option value="CorporateHR">CorporateHR</option>
              <option value="CorporateIT">CorporateIT</option>
              <option value="CorporateLegal">CorporateLegal</option>
              <option value="CorporateLogistics">CorporateLogistics</option>
              <option value="CorporateTax">CorporateTax</option>
              <option value="EMEAPackaging">EMEAPackaging</option>
              <option value="EMEAPapers">EMEAPapers</option>
              <option value="GCF">GCF</option>
              <option value="MillManufacturing">MillManufacturing</option>
              <option value="MillSupport">MillSupport</option>
              <option value="NAIPGContainer">NAIPGContainer</option>
              <option value="NAIPGContainerboard">NAIPGContainerboard</option>
              <option value="NAIPGRecycling">NAIPGRecycling</option>
              <option value="NAP">NAP</option>
              <option value="SouthAmerica">SouthAmerica</option>
              <option value="zConnectivity">zConnectivity</option>
              <option value="zSylvamo">zSylvamo</option>
            </select>

          </td>

          <!-- * Input for Deployer Project *-->
          <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordProjectName">
            <input type="text" id="DEPLOYER_PROJECT" name="Project Name" class="vcheck" placeholder="">
          </td>


          <!-- * Deployer_Candidate *-->
          <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="titleDeployerCandidate">
            <select id="DEPLOYER_CANDIDATE" class="vcheck">

              <!-- * Picklist for TP *-->
              <option value="PRODJ (wm53a/b/c 10000)">PRODJ (wm53a/b/c 10000)
              </option>
              <option value="PRODR (wm53a/b/c 12000)">PRODR (wm53a/b/c 12000)
              </option>
              <option value="PRODXA (wm54a/b/c 21000)">PRODXA (wm54a/b/c 21000)
              </option>
              <option value="PRODXS (wm54a/b/c 20000)">PRODXS (wm54a/b/c 20000)
              </option>
              <option value="PRODXE (wm53a/b/c 11000)">PRODXE (wm53a/b/c 11000)
              </option>
              <option value="-------------------">-------------------</option>
              <option value="PRODAD1 (wm54a/b/c 60000)">PRODAD1 (wm54a/b/c 60000)
              </option>
              <option value="PRODAD2 (wm54a/b/c 61000)">PRODAD2 (wm54a/b/c 61000)
              </option>
              <option value="-------------------">-------------------</option>
              <option value="MAPGRP1 (wm52a/b/c 40k/41k/42k)">MAPGRP1 (wm52a/b/c 40k/41k/42k)
              </option>
            </select>

          </td>

          <!-- * Input for Description *-->
          <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDeployerCandidate" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" id="DESCRIPTION" name="Description" placeholder="" class="vcheck" style="resize: vertical; width: 100%; height: 4.5em;" </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- * Add & Remove buttons *-->
    <div class="btn-group2">
      <div id="addRemoveButons" class="dt-buttons" style="visibility:hidden">
        <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button" id="recordAddBtn2" title="Add new record" style="display: inline-block;">
                                        <span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
                                    </button>
        <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button" id="recordAddBtn" title="Add new record">
                                        <span><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></span>
                                    </button>
        <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button" id="recordRemoveBtn" title="Remove last record" style="display: none">
                                        <span><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
                                    </button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I have a table. It is causing two problems. The first problem was that it was suppose to loop through the columns get the values and than insert the number of rows. Problem is no matter how many rows are added only the last row information is being used. So instead of returning for example (row 1: 1, 2, 3) (row 2: 4,5, 6) & (row 3:7, 8, 9) for instance all three rows return 7,8, 9 in the input boxes. Not sure why it doing this because it suppose to loop through the input than insert into the db and than loop again. Instead it looks like it looping through the inputs until it gets to the last row and inserting three times using the last row inputs.Another user pointed out I was looping to insert after the loop over the rows. Each loop over the rows overwrites the variables from the previous row. So I move my second loop inside the first loop but now it is running for infinity and crashing my browser.

Update: So there was a couple errors in my code. First was the return statement I was using to prevent crashes also broke the code. Second was reusing i when I should use a different variable (j in this instance), and third was using the wrong variable to loop through because it was looping indefinitely.Thank you everyone for the tips!

Comment: `"ReferenceError: $ is not defined"` please include jQuery in your demo and ensure it runs as expected (though obviously test that it works as expected in a browser that you can close when it tries to run for infinity). Incidentally, we only need the relevant code (the dB code is very much unnecessary; please: minimise the code to illustrate only the relevant problem).

Comment: Sorry I am confused the db is necessary isn't it? That the goal of the loop is to loop through all the inputs and than insert.

Comment: Don't use the same variable name for nested loops!   `for (var i = 1, row...) { ... for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { ... } }`.   The inner loop is changing the value of `i` of the outer loop.  Although there is also a strange ` return i;` in there as well.

Comment: The problem you're having is related to the looping, and retrieving, of values in the `<input>` elements; we're (I hope *obviously*) not going to be working with your live dB, so we don't need that information. What we want - and, seriously, I'm trying to be supportive - is to see the minimum relevant "*[mcve]*" code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: `(row = table.rows[i]);` this line is quite confusing; shouldn't it be `i<table.rows.length`?

Comment: Why do you set the variable `row` and then not use it? Your code would be easier to read and write if you replaced `table.rows[i]` with `row`. You even said so in the comment!

Comment: I gotcha David. No live DB this is just for a test run. I am aware of SQL injection. Thanks for Abrar I swap the line to what you recommend. Freedomn your right I swap the i to a j in the second loop and remove the return i. Hopefully this should fix the issue.

Comment: Great news the tips work! The code is now running as expected for the most part and crashing!

Comment: @AbrarHossain that syntax was convenient in the days before Array.map and similar.  You could assign the current element to a variable and if it was undefined (because index out of range) it would break the loop.  `for (let i = 0, row; row = arr[i]; i++)` -> i is the index, row is the element.